# If $f,g>0$, f increasing and g decreasing on interval $(0,1)$ then, what conditions imposed for that $fg$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$?

Tags: special-functions

The question is about of the conditions over $f$ and $g$ for the next:

If $f,g>0$, $f$ increasing, $g$ decreasing then what conditions imposed for that $fg$ is decreasing in $(0,1)$?

Where $f,g,fg: (0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: There is no general result available. You can find examples where the product is increasing, decreasing, and none of the previous. Signs do play a big role here.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ are derivable functions, than we want:
$$
(fg)'=f'g+fg'<0
$$

Since $f'g'<0$ this means:
$$
\frac{g}{g'}+\frac{f}{f'}>0 \iff \frac{g}{g'}>-\frac{f}{f'}
$$

That can be useful if we know something more about the two function.

Comment: Maybe the last condition is better if we invert? $(\log g)' < -(\log f)'$?

Comment: It's more elegant, but I don't know if it's more useful.

Comment: I guess I have problems with zeroes of the functions. But I was thinking that saying that $\log g$ grows slower than $\log(1/f)$ was a pretty intuitive thing. No big deal. :)